# How to test why a website is down?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have a few websites hosted on ubuntu server. The server has 3 ip addresses and the one of the websites is pointed to one ip address and it is working. the other websites are on pointed to another ip address and all of them are down. The error says that it cannot connect to the website. The website that I'm worried about is http://amerihomesgroup.com. could this be a problem with apache? I haven't changed the settings for this except I changed form an internal dns to something off site. The websites will be up for a few days and then off for another few.

---

The only think in the error log is

```
[Sun Aug 12 11:22:36 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 12 11:22:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I am vpning in to the server so it cant really be down. The ip is correct.

---

```
as0t0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:115212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:126152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:200
      RX bytes:31897718 (31.8 MB)  TX bytes:96598640 (96.5 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:9f:30:c4
      inet addr:173.165.134.13  Bcast:173.165.134.15  Mask:255.255.255.248
      inet6 addr: fe80::230:48ff:fe9f:30c4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:50741898 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:42443370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:47892044123 (47.8 GB)  TX bytes:10339161772 (10.3 GB)
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0xe000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:9f:30:c4
      inet addr:173.165.134.12  Bcast:173.165.134.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0xe000

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:9f:30:c4
      inet addr:173.165.134.11  Bcast:173.165.134.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0xe000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:9f:30:c5
      inet addr:192.168.8.254  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::230:48ff:fe9f:30c5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:45697259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:50623015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:9869007722 (9.8 GB)  TX bytes:47344187732 (47.3 GB)
      Interrupt:28

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:25822 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25822 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:4641338 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:4641338 (4.6 MB)
```

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`?

Comment: The hostname resolves to 173.165.134.11 is this correct ?

Comment: It's not responding to ping. Maybe the server is down? :D

Comment: Or telnet 173.165.134.11 80

Comment: the only think in the error log is `[Sun Aug 12 11:22:36 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 12 11:22:44 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
/var/log/apache2/error.log`
I am vpning in to the server so it cant really be down. The ip is correct.

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and if so what are it's contents ?

Comment: it is `NameVirtualHost *:80 Listen 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a tracert to the site to see how far in the route it is getting? This may provide more of a clue to where it is failing.

Comment: i did  a trecert on it and it stops at comcast with an ip of 68.87.170.246. would this mean that it is something to do with comcast

Comment: Most ISPs have a service status page or telephone number you can call - it would be worth checking to see if they are having problems before you continue going over your connection(s) further.

Comment: if my firewall was blocking it would it just stop at the hop before the firewall?

Comment: thanks I didn't even think to try a trace route. I just called Comcast and they fixed it. Thanks again this has been casing me problems for weeks now

Answer (score 2):

The issue does not seem to be within apache configuration but rather on your network configuration.

Opening `http://173.165.134.13` on a web browser displays a page, and is pingable from the internet.

However, `173.165.134.11` is neither pingable nor browseable.

Your main interface, `eth0`, shows a mask of `255.255.255.248`, ie a subnet address of `173.165.134.8/29`. However, `eth0:1` and `eth0:2` have a different netmask, `255.255.255.0`, and are in the `173.165.134.0/24` subnet.

Try to set their netmask accordingly, and see if it works better:

```
# ifconfig eth0:1 173.165.134.12/28
# ifconfig eth0:2 173.165.134.11/28
```

Edit:
Since you corrected your configuration, the situation is different. I get "Welcome to trizon 404" on `http://173.165.134.11`, and the IP address is reachable.

You now have an apache issue, not anymore a network issue.

Comment: it didn't change anything but good catch

Answer (score 0):

It is really not a problem with apache. You have to check whether the IP address are assigned correctly.

Please paste output of ifconfig, so that I can provide more help.

Note: If the problem is of apache's, ping should have been worked anyway.

Comment: The ifconfig is ok, in my opinion.